# Cayley's Theorem and it's representation

Tags: group-theory

Here is a question that I am working currently at the moment:

> The symmetric group $S_3$ consists of the six permutations $$\{Id, (12).(13),(23),(123),(132)\}$$
>
> The Cayley homomorphism can be applied to this group. In this way, we get a homomorphism $f: S_3 \rightarrow S_6$. Write out the Cayley representation $P_{(123)} = f((123))$.

This is how to multiplication table is defined in my book, assuming that $a = (12)$, $b = (132)$, $c = (13)$, $d = (123)$, $e = (23)$ and $Id$ is the identity element.
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
& Id & a & b & c & d& e&\\ \hline
 Id& Id & a &b &c &d&e&\\ 
 a& a &Id  &c  &b &e&d &\\ 
 b& b & e &d  &a & Id& c&\\ 
 c& c &d  &e  &Id & a& b&\\
 d& d &c  &Id  &e &b&a&\\
 e& e& b&a&d&c&Id\\
\end{array}

Basically, Arthur Cayley claims that "every group is isomorphic to a group of permutations", also known as [Cayley's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem). How can apply this to solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

A group G with order $n$ is isomorphic to the group of left multiplications $L(G) = \{l(g)\mid g\in G\}$, where $l(g):G\rightarrow G: h\mapsto gh$; $g\mapsto l(g)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: This wouldn't apply to right multiplications because $S_3$ is *not* symmetric, correct?

Comment: But, per se, this embeds $G$ into $S_G$, not into $S_{|G|}$.